STM Nucleo F091RC: Only 4 Out of 8 USART Ports Working with HardwareSerial Library – How to Fix the Remaining Ports?
I'm using Visual Studio Code with PlatformIO and the Arduino framework to work with the STM Nucleo F091RC. I'm encountering an issue where only 4 out of the 8 USART ports are responding when using the HardwareSerial library. When I attempt to add the fifth USART, the code only loops four times before requiring a reset. The code functions correctly with four USART ports. How can I fix the remaining 8 ports?
Project code:
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
#include <AsyncDelay.h>

// Max code receive timer is created
uint8_t maxReceiveTimer = 10;
AsyncDelay receiveTimer;

// Definieer SoftwareSerial object
HardwareSerial mySerial1(PA3, PA2); // RX, TX
HardwareSerial mySerial2(PC3, PC2); // RX, TX
HardwareSerial mySerial3(PA10, PA9); // RX, TX
HardwareSerial mySerial4(PC5, PC4);  // RX, TX
HardwareSerial mySerial5(PA0, PA1);  // RX, TX
HardwareSerial mySerial6(PD2, PC12);  // RX, TX
HardwareSerial mySerial7(PC1, PC0);  // RX, TX
HardwareSerial mySerial8(PC7, PC6);  // RX, TX



void setup() {
  
  mySerial1.begin(115200); // communication with SoftwareSerial
  mySerial2.begin(115200);
  mySerial3.begin(115200);
  mySerial4.begin(115200);
  mySerial5.begin(115200);
  mySerial6.begin(115200);  
  mySerial7.begin(115200);  
  mySerial8.begin(115200);
  delay(500);
  mySerial1.println("Setup Ready");
}

void loop() {
  mySerial1.print("serial 111111\n");
  mySerial2.print("serial 222222\n");
  mySerial3.print("serial 333333\n");
  mySerial4.print("serial 444444\n");
  //mySerial5.print("serial 555555\n");(when uncommend no serial output from all ports)
  //mySerial6.print("serial 666666\n");(when uncommend no serial output from all ports)
  //mySerial7.print("serial 777777\n");(when uncommend no serial output from all ports)
  //mySerial8.print("serial 888888\n");(when uncommend no serial output from all ports)

  delay(500);
}


Did you noticed this topic where it handle all USARTs for STM32?
ANSWER

Yes, I have read the topic and tried to control the USART directly. I am using PlatformIO to interface with the board. However, when testing the USART ports, only USART 2 worked; this is by default a serial port. All other ports do not have this configuration and therefore do not respond in the program. I have configured the chip with 8 UARTs in the STM IDE, but I don't know how to transfer this configuration to PlatformIO because the STM IDE generates many different files, and I also can't find anything like a "board.txt" in PlatformIO.
